# How to do a distinct count based on a conditional

Tags: powerbi

So my problem is simple, I want to create a measure to do a distinct count
But when I do it (considering the example),

I count the distinct vessels, but the result give me 2, because you see there are two vessels, V1 and V2
But I need to count only the vessels which all lines are loaded, so It will be just 1, because only V2 has all lines marked as "Yes", any idea how to do?

| Vessel | Loaded |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | Yes |
| V1 | No |
| V1 | Yes |
| V2 | Yes |
| V2 | Yes |

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Custom Column** first as below-

```
all_loaded = 

var current_row_vassel = your_table_name[Vessel]
var count_no = 
CALCULATE(
    count(your_table_name[Vessel]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Vessel] = current_row_vassel
            && your_table_name[Loaded] = "No"
    )
)

RETURN IF(count_no > 0, 0, 1)
```

And then a **Measure** as below-

```
total_vassel = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Vessel]),
    your_table_name[all_loaded] = 1
)
```